# Cant set right frame for ImageView

Tags: swift, frame

I cant set my UIImageView as half size of my tableview.backgroundview in upper part of my controller.

i tried to set origin of avatar as origin view, but it doesnt work.

```
    let avatar =  UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let imgageOfAvatar = UIImage(named: "avatar.jpg")
    avatar.image = imgageOfAvatar

   avatar.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin, y: self.view.frame.origin , width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2)
    avatar.frame.origin = self.view.frame.origin

    //avatar.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.tableView.addSubview(avatar)
    self.tableView.sendSubview(toBack: avatar)
```

https://pp.userapi.com/c847120/v847120175/19f9cf/128kU2yWq-E.jpg

Comment: most like you want `.scaleAspectFit` However, adding subviews to table view won't reliable work since table views are essentially scroll views and frames there work rather differently. Don't add subviews to table views. You should consider using `tableView.backgroundView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

avatar.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.origin.x
avatar.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y

avatar.frame = CGRect(origin:self.view.frame.origin, size: width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2)

Answer (score 0):

you should add it to view like this:

```
    let avatar =  UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let imgageOfAvatar = UIImage(named: "avatar.jpg")
    avatar.image = imgageOfAvatar

    avatar.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y , width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2)
    avatar.frame.origin = self.view.frame.origin

    self.view.insertSubview(avatar, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the intended result
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUon7.png)

```
    let avatar = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let imgageOfAvatar = UIImage(named: "dog.jpeg")
    avatar.image = imgageOfAvatar
    avatar.frame = CGRect(origin: self.view.frame.origin,
                          size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width,
                                       height: self.view.frame.height / 2))
    self.tableview.addSubview(avatar)
    self.tableview.sendSubviewToBack(avatar)
```